# CMake - How to export a library with private dependencies

Tags: cmake

I am trying to export a library from a CMake project.  Internally, I've broken this library up into multiple sub-targets.  I would now like to export just the full public library, without needing my private library binaries.  The following doesn't work.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)

project(export-mwe)

add_library(priv priv.cpp)

add_library(exp-lib exp-lib.cpp)
target_link_libraries(exp-lib PRIVATE priv)

install(TARGETS exp-lib EXPORT export-mwe DESTINATION lib)

install(EXPORT export-mwe DESTINATION .)
```

When I try generating this project I get an error.

```
CMake Error: install(EXPORT "export-mwe" ...) includes target "exp-lib" which requires target "priv" that is not in the export set.
```

How can I export only `exp-lib` in this example, without having to export `priv` with it?

Comment: You cannot export a library interface with insufficient dependencies. You will have to write a package config file. See cmake-buildsystem(7) and cmake-packages(7).

Answer (score 3):

The library `exp-lib` is **static** (this is default on Linux), so it is NOT "physically" linked with `priv`: creation of a static library doesn't calls a linker at all.

When applied to a static library, CMake interprets `target_link_libraries` in a specific manner: the actual linkage with the `priv` library file is **moved** to the every target, which links with `exp-lib`.

That is, further

```
target_link_libraries(shared-lib exp-lib)
```

will be translated to the linker's command line

```
ld -o shared-lib.so <...> exp-lib.a deps.a
```

When a static library is exported, CMake exposes the same behavior:
Any target, which links with IMPORTED target `exp-lib` via `target_link_libraries`, automatically gets linkage with `deps.a`. To implement such behavior, CMake needs to know where `deps.a` is installed.

While installation location of `deps.a` can be obtained from `install(TARGETS deps)` command, CMake still requires that the installation be exported: `install(TARGETS deps EXPORT export-mwe)`.

Comment: Isn't STATIC the default?

Comment: Hmm, most likely libraries are *STATIC* by default. I have just tested your code on my machine (Linux, CMake 3.4.1), and have got very strange results: 1. `priv` is noted in export file when and only when `exp-lib` is *STATIC* (!!), type of `priv` library doesn't affect on that. 2. Neither error nor warning is generated with any combination of *STATIC* / *SHARED* for `exp-lib` and `priv` libraries.

Comment: What if `priv` was a header-only library defined with `add_library(INTERFACE)` followed by target_include_directories(INTERFACE)? Shouldn't it be excluded from the export file? I have this case and cmake tell me in an error message that I have to export priv as well.

Comment: "... cmake tell me in an error message that I have to export priv as well."- Just do what CMake tells you. Like normal libraries, *INTERFACE* libraries can be exported and installed too.

Comment: As John notes, `STATIC` is default, and I can confirm that this doesn't solve the issue (with CMake 3.10.2).

Comment: `STATIC` is the default unless `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS` is set, and then `SHARED` is the default. I just tried it and if I explicitly set `STATIC` then the information is indeed not stored in the export file.

Comment: That's because if it's linked as a shared library, downstream libraries need to know where to locate the shared library dependency.

Comment: The answer has been rewritten, as old variant was completely wrong. Actually, it is STATIC nature of `exp-lib` library causes given error message. So my observations in the [first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47534442/cmake-how-to-export-a-library-with-private-dependencies/47540871#comment82052074_47540871) have logical explanations.