# Link internal dependency to external library and expose it to different project in CMake

Tags: cmake

I have a problem that I'm trying to introduce dependency between 3 library in CMake.
Let's say libInternal, libExternal and MainProgram. And I would like to do something like:

`target_link_libraries(libExternal PRIVATE libInternal)`

And the with `libExternalConfig.cmake` just to add in MainProgram package like:

`find_package(libExternal REQUIRED)`

The problem is that CMake is failing with:

`The following imported targets are referenced, but are missing: libInternal`

Is there any chance to resolve it somehow?

I tried to include `libInternal` as in `libExternalConfig` and so on, but nothing helps.

Below you can see my CMakeLists.txt files:
libInternal CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(libInternal)

add_library(Internal
            OBJECT
            files included)

target_link_libraries(Internal PRIVATE lib included)

target_include_directories(Internal
                           INTERFACE $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/public/include>
                           PRIVATE $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}>
                                   $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}>/public/include/internal)


install(TARGETS Internal EXPORT ${PROJECT_NAME}
        ARCHIVE  DESTINATION lib
        LIBRARY  DESTINATION lib
        RUNTIME  DESTINATION bin)

install(EXPORT ${PROJECT_NAME} DESTINATION config)

export(TARGETS Internal FILE ${PROJECT_NAME}.cmake)
```

and libExternal CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(libExternal VERSION 0.0.1)

add_library(External
            STATIC
            files included)

target_link_libraries(External PRIVATE Internal)

target_include_directories(External 
                           INTERFACE $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/public/include>
                           PRIVATE $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}>
                                   $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}>/public/include/external)

install(TARGETS External 
        EXPORT ${PROJECT_NAME}
        ARCHIVE  DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
        LIBRARY  DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
        INCLUDES DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}
        RUNTIME  DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR})

install(EXPORT ${PROJECT_NAME}
        DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/${PROJECT_NAME}
        FILE ${PROJECT_NAME}.cmake)

install(DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/public/include/ DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR})

include(CMakePackageConfigHelpers)
write_basic_package_version_file(${PROJECT_NAME}ConfigVersion.cmake
        COMPATIBILITY SameMajorVersion)
install(FILES ${PROJECT_NAME}Config.cmake ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}ConfigVersion.cmake
        DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/${PROJECT_NAME})

export(TARGETS External FILE ${PROJECT_NAME}.cmake)
```

Comment: You need to add `find_dependency(libInternal)` to the `libExternalConfig.cmake` file. About reasons why do you need do that even in case of PRIVATE linkage, see e.g. that [my anwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47540871/3440745). (Your libExternal is a STATIC library, isn't)?

Comment: Yes it is. The `libInternal` is OBJECT. I was trying to add `find_dependency(libInternal)` syntax, but it's also failing with no `libInternalConfig.cmake` or `FindlibInternal.cmake`

Comment: I added how my CMakeLists.txt files look like in problem description

Comment: @Tsyvarev I know it was closed, but I don't get answer from "already has an answer" question.

Comment: Your `libExternal` project performs `target_link_libraries(External PRIVATE Internal)`, but how it obtains `Internal` target? I see no `find_package(Internal)` or similar in it. Also, the error message you show refers to `libInternal` target, which is defined in none of your projects. Please, (re-)check that the code you show actually triggers the posted error.

Comment: It triggers when I expose external lib to different project.

External lib is building well on local side. Internal is exposed locally by 
`install(EXPORT ${PROJECT_NAME} DESTINATION config)

export(TARGETS Internal FILE ${PROJECT_NAME}.cmake)`

So there's no different way to include it than create `FindInternal.cmake` or `InternalConfig.cmake` and add `find_package(Internal)` inside libExternal library?

Comment: I don't understand your question and see no relation of it with the problem stated in the question post. If you want to know when to use `FindXXX.cmake` script or `XXXConfig.cmake` one, then you could read description in the CMake documentation: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-packages.7.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255893/discussion-between-pagorek-and-tsyvarev).